# Pot sticking to induction cooktop

Tags: induction

I recently bought a Max Burton 6400 induction cooktop.  I used it a few times with some pans I already own and had no problem.  Today I wanted to heat some milk up quickly, and I used [a cheap Ikea sauce pan](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/60101157/).  The milk heated up fine, but when I tried to remove the pot, it had become stuck to the surface.  I turned the cooktop off, but it was still stuck.  I finally was able to slide it to the edge and pull it off, throwing hot milk all over my kitchen.

Has anyone experienced this with an induction cooktop before?  Is it considered a malfunction?  And should I blame the pot or the cooktop?

Comment: Hmmmm, looks like a physics question... =D

Comment: Did you notice if the pot was sticking before you used it on the induction top?

Comment: It slid, but you couldn't lift it?  Was the pot wet before it went down, because that's sounding like it could've been the issue when you get a really thin layer of liquid between two objects, and air pressure holds them together.

Comment: @Joe a good conjecture. I've been thinking about this from a magnetic standpoint, which would similarly be overcome by sliding. I like the idea of suction, though.

Comment: @Catija : oh, right ... induction uses magnets.  Another good point.  That one can be fixed by turning off the stove before trying to lift the pan.  Let me go try to test it.

Comment: @Catija : okay, test results : it's difficult to tell w/ a cast iron pan, but it did seem heavier when I went to lift it.  It wasn't so strong that I lifted my hotplate, even with it set to '10'.  I tried something lighter (a steel baking tray), and it got hot so fast in the middle that it warped within seconds, so I couldn't do a good test.  Most of my pans are annodized aluminum, stainess steel or cast iron, so I didn't have anything else to test with.  I think that magnets *are* a factor, but I don't know if it's so much that it'd be difficult to lift the pan.

Comment: And I forgot just how quickly induction burners get things hot ... making me think that my 'little bit of water' theory might actually be less like a mastic and more like sealing a mason jar : if the water evaporates, then cools, with a pan that makes a good seal around the edge, it could seal itself to the flat cooktop ... but there's mention that the pan was still hot (as it had hot milk in it).

Comment: Induction stoves do not have magnets in them. They have copper coils which when AC current is applied creates an oscillating magnetic field. The net magnetic attraction in theory should be zero. My bet is on liquid under a very flat or concave pan.

Comment: Pretty sure the pot was not wet when I used it.

Comment: Has the issue recurred since you asked the question? I'm imagine with all of the comments you've been wary of moisture under the pan.

Comment: I haven't used this pot on the induction cooktop since I posted the comment.  I'll probably try it again this weekend and report back.

Answer (score 7):

I am guessing you had a bit of fluid either on the bottom of the pan or on the top of your stove. It could have been almost any fluid including water. Even though your pans can get really hot, water trapped under a pan doesn't seem to boil away very quickly, and the longer the pot sits on top of the fluid, the thinner it is pressed, thus turning into a suction problem because there is no effective fluid surface (thickness) for air to slurp in under the pot.

I cook mostly with cast iron, so the irregularity of the surface minimizes this effect a great deal.

Make sure your pot bottoms and stove surface are dry and clean. Obviously they'll still get greasy, especially during heavy cooking sessions, but try to keep the grease level to a minimum, and wipe down the stove between the burners as you go.

Answer (score 2):

My SIMPLE SOLUTION to this that hopefully will work for others as well is first I placed and tried to insert a plastic measuring tape edge to get in between the stuck pan and the stove top of the induction cooker. When it was only able to get in between the two a little, I put tissues around the bottom of the pan to absorb the liquid underneath it. Threw the wet tissues and placed new dry tissues.

Then I used a flat metal spatula and inserted it in between the two and very gently tried to lift the pan off the stove top to avoid scratching or damaging both while the tissues are there to also act as a mini lever for the spatula.

To my surprise, the pan got unstuck easily. (I waited for the induction cooker and pan to cool first before I did all this. I actually slept over this issue due to the stress it has brought me and when I woke up this solution came to my mind.)

Answer (score 1):

My induction pan stuck to the induction hob which naturally made me panic! I was making homemade soup and it had to simmer for awhile. To resolve this I realised the pan needed to cool down. I turned everything off and removed the soup from the pot by using a ladle. Once the pot had cooled down and with a little gentle pressure I slid the pot to the edge and then lifted it. No damage to the hob. Water was trapped beneath the pot and the hob.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work in a foundry that used induction oven to melt aluminum,zinc, and brass. I would say it was liquid suction

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, I too believe it was the suction.
Use this or something similar:

Tescoma Induktions-Adapterplatte, ø 21 cm https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00N1TFH5U/ref=cm_sw_r_wa_apa_glt_i_8N98N0TVX219CFPF5TNW?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score -1):

It is entirely possible that your pan melted a bit.

Many materials will just not warm up if you put them on an induction stove. But if you have aluminium which is thin enough, it can melt. There are people who melt alu foil on induction cooktops as a prank. I suspect that, if your pot was thin enough, or if it was layered with aluminium as the contact surface (and layered/sandwich bottoms are common in cookware), it could have heated too, and melted and fused with the cooktop.

Another way to fuse would in principle be bad enamel, if the pot itself heated enough to soften a thin layer of enamel. But this is very unlikely, since enamel has a much higher melting point than aluminium. I have used enameled pots, including cheap ones, without any problem.

This is not the only possibility, of course. As Escoce said, a burnt-on liquid can also make it stick somewhat. But if this is the case, you should be able to separate it without damaging the glass by simply pushing harder on the pot. If they are completely fused, a melted bottom is more likely.

If this is what happened, you should blame the pot, and only use pots with a "ready for induction" sign on the bottom. The only exception should be cookware for which you are sure that its bottom layer is either steel or iron. Check steel with a magnet for conductivity.

Comment: This is a well formatted answer with some obvious effort applied, but the scientific half of my brain is having some issues. Take a propane torch and try to melt solder onto a room temperature piece of glass. It will flake off with little effort. The fact that he had liquid in the pan makes melting the pan astronomically unlikely. Ever tried soldering a copper pipe with a tiny bit of water in it? Best regards.

Comment: Interesting point about the liquid. I haven't tried the soldering you describe. If it is comparable, than you are probably right. On the other hand, induction heating works differently than soldering - the heat is concentrated in a much smaller portion of the metal (skin effect). I know it is sufficient to melt a sheet of foil, I don't know if the water will be sufficient cooling to prevent the melting. I'd love to see more definitive info, but there is no way I'm sacrificing my cooktop for this experiment!